# Nightwatch to select option from select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, nightwatch.js

I am trying to use nightwatch.js to select an option from a select box.

I have the code:

```
    this.browser.click('select[name="month"]')
        .pause(1000)
        .click('option[value="3"]')
        .click('select[name="day"]')
        .pause(1000)
        .click('option[value="6"]')
        .click('select[name="year"]')
        .pause(1000)
        .click('option[value="1989"]');
```

It selects the correct month, year on the page but not the day. Here's the HTML for the select box for the day:

```
<select aria-label="Day" id="day" name="day" data-validatorGroup="bday" data-component="selectbox">
    <option selected="selected" value="" aria-label="Date of birth">
        Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="29">29</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>
         </select>
```

Does anyone know why its not selecting the proper day?

Comment: May you share all html code may be there is another select with the same name may be not sure;

Comment: My answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112583/cannot-locate-element-using-recursion-after-it-found-it-as-visible/37129429#37129429

Answer (score 30):

According to [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nightwatchjs/C_DJIHJctyU/Za44qp2wHzkJ), this works:

```
.click('#myselectbox option[value=somevalue]')
```

Comment: how would you do that outside of NW in vanilla js?

Comment: thx, I'm getting the select change with the change event, but the event doesn't show what option is selected. I guess I need to query the select after?

Comment: **document.querySelector("#myselectbox option[value=somevalue]").click()** doesn't change the value of the selected option in the UI.

Comment: `s = document.querySelector('#myselectbox'); s.selectedIndex = s.querySelector('option[id=o2]').index; s.onchange()`

Answer (score 15):

The following syntax seems to be more reliable:

```
.click('select[id="myselectbox"] option[value="somevalue"]')
```

Comment: Please give explanations for down votes, I'd like to learn more. Cees Timmerman's answer looks good but doesn't work for me.

Comment: Well, my guess is that ```#myselectbox``` is more efficient version of ```select[id="myselectbox"]```. If it doesn't work you probably have more then one element with id ```#myselectbox``` on a page, which is considered to be a bad practice.

Comment: This works with Chrome driver 85 and nightwatch 1.5.1. Thanks men!!

Answer (score 8):

You may try the following, it works for me.

```
<option value="2">2</option>
...
.setValue('select[id="day"]','2')
```

if you have different value than the text in your option

e.g. `<option value="123">abc</option>`

You do `.setValue ('select[id="yourselectid"]','abc')`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do with Page Object, you have to use callback.

```
sectionInfo.click("@selectOwner",()=>{
  sectionInfo.click("option[value='owner']");
});
```

Comment: This is definitely the best way to do it,  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
.click("#selectid option:nth-child(1)")
```

This also works using class identifier -

e.g.

```
.click(".selectclass option:nth-child(1)")
```

Setting the nth-child to 1 will choose the first item in the dropdown.

Setting to 2 will select the second value, etc. etc.

Hope this helps for those of you who had no luck with previously stated solutions.