# How to test VueJS select field with Nightwatch?

Tags: vuejs2, nightwatch.js

[image: form layout]

I have to use Nightwatch to test a site built with Django REST + VueJS.
Since fields are named, for almost all fields I can use this:

```
.waitForElementVisible('input[name=Name]', 1000)
.setValue('input[name=Name]', 'NightwatchTestIpa')
```

But, for some reason I don't know, select field doesn't work with the usual syntax recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020702/nightwatch-to-select-option-from-select-box)

```
.click('select[name=Type] option[value=TestType]')
```

I've also tried `.click('select[name=Type] option[description=TestType]')` because `description` is the attribute rendered from `ipa-types`

I already checked the existence of TestType item.

Does anyone know if VueJS has some peculiarity with select fields, or what am I doing wrong?

If you want, you can find the entire project on Github, [back-end](https://github.com/fga-gpp-mds/2017.2-SiGI-Op_API) and [front-end](https://github.com/fga-gpp-mds/2017.2-SiGI-Op).