# Unable to press enter using nightwatch

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I am trying to press ENTER using nightwatch using below code in my test

```
module.exports = {
'Enter Text'(client) {
  client
  .url(url)
  .waitForElementVisible('element', 1000)
  .setValue('input[id="new-todo"]', ['abcdefgh', client.Keys.ENTER])
  .pause(10000)
  .end();
```

it opens chrome browser, sets the value but does not press ENTER. My application needs this to be done as pressing enter is the only option.

Below is the HTML code for the part I am trying to automate

```
 <header id="header">
<h1>todos</h1>
<input id="new-todo" disabled placeholder="What needs to be done?" autofocus data-weave="troopjs-todos/widget/create">
</header>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Without it, we cannot be of much help here. I suspect though that you need to add a click command or a send keys with the enter.

Comment: @QualiT I have added the HTML. Can you plz check

Answer (score 0):

<del>I am assuming that there is some listener on that input field so that when it loses focus it saves. Assuming that, try this:</del>

EDIT: The problem may be that that array in .setValue is not handled correctly. Try this:

```
module.exports = {
'Enter Text'(client) {
  client
  .url(url)
  .waitForElementVisible('element', 1000)
  .setValue('input[id="12345"]', 'abcdefgh')
  .keys(client.Keys.ENTER)
  .pause(10000)
  .end();
}
```

Comment: Tried this. Doesn't work. There is a small script at the end of the page. Does that make a difference ?

document.getElementById("new-todo").disabled=false;

Comment: A couple of questions: is your input a search field? Presumably it return a dynamic list of guesses at what you are searching for. In that case, I presume you'd know which response you want to click. Do you want to randomly go to a specific result, similar to Google's "I Feel Lucky" button (https://www.google.com/)?

Comment: As you can see in the link there is no element I need to click on. just enter the characters and press enter is the only option.

Comment: Tried with above code. It still doesn't work. Can you please try the above link at your end and see where is the issue? I shall be thankful to you for this :)

Comment: Ah, useful thank you. I have updated the description with another option.

Comment: I'm also curious what version of nightwatch you are using and what browser you're testing with. Selenium version might also be relevant. If you are using Chrome, add the version of Chrome and the Chromedriver

Comment: I am using chromedriver latest version (ChromeDriver 2.45), selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0 jar and nightwatch v1.0.18, Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Apologies, I have been pulled into other work and haven't had time to look into this. I recall from past experience that .keys wasn't always reliable when I last used it, but in my search for how I handled it I have come up empty because those repos are not mine anymore. Though after looking at my Stackoverflow history, my suspicion is that option 2 at on this will work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48775667/3182958